# junit testing without static methods

Tags: java, testing, junit, compiler-errors, static

I need to create tests for various functions, which are not static (which I'm not allowed to change).
E.g.

```
public Double average(int[] scores) {
    int sum = Arrays.stream(scores).sum();
    return (double) sum/scores.length;
}
```

Test:

```
public void testAverage (){
    int[] scores = {25, 100, 90, 72};
    Double expected = 59.25;
    Double result = LogicProblems.average(scores);
    assertEquals(expected, result);
}
```

interface:
`public Double average(int[] scores);`

Doing so, I get the error message "can't call a non-static method from static context"

Could you tell me why the context is static, and how to work around/with it?

Comment: If you want to call a non-static method defined in the `LogicProblems` class, you need to use an instance of `LogicProblems`. That's what not being static means. Depending on how the class is written it might be as simple as `new LogicProblems().average(scores)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't change the code of `LogicProblems`, you need to instantiate it in the test:

```java
public void testAverage (){
    int[] scores = {25, 100, 90, 72};
    Double expected = 59.25;
    LogicProblems lp = new LogicProblemsImpl(); // Or better yet, in a @Before method
    Double result = lp.average(scores);
    assertEquals(expected, result);
}
```

Comment: when I try the latter, it says that lp is abstract and cannot be instantiated

Comment: @idanicoleherbert presumably you have a concrete class that extends it you can use?

Comment: I have a class that implements it, but if i change the implementation methods to static, it gives me the error that I can't override the instance method "average int[]"

Comment: @idanicoleherbert you need to instantiate the concrete class that extends `LogicProblems`. I've edited my answer to demonstrate that under the assumption it's called simply `LogicProbelmsImpl`. If it's called something else, just replace the name (and pass the necessary arguments to its constructor if it requires any)

Comment: Understood. Thanks, it now works. I appreciate you're help.